# Characteristic function of an independent variable, does it involve complex values?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let

$$ x_k = \begin{cases}  1 & \mathrm{prob}  (1/2)\\ -1 &\mathrm{prob} (1/2) \end{cases}$$

be independient random variables.

Show that the characteristic function of the random variable

$$ \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... + x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ 
is equal to $\left(\cos\frac{w}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n $

---

The characteristic function is defined as

$$ \phi_x(w) = \sum e^i{iwx}f(x)$$

for discrete variables.

Then we have

$$ E(e^{iwX}) = e^{iw(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + e^{iw(-1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iw}+e^{-iw}) = \cos w .$$

And that's where I'm stuck.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that relates the characteristic function of a sum of mutually independent random variables to the characteristic functions of the individual variables?

Answer (score 0):

If $Y_j,1\leqslant j\leqslant n$ are independent random variable with respective characteristic functions $\varphi_j$, then the characteristic function of $\sum_{j=1}^nY_j$ is given by $\prod_{j=1}^n\varphi_j(w)$.

Applying this to $Y_j:= n^{-1/2}  x_j$, we obtain that the characteristic function $\phi_n$ of $n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^nx_j$ is equal to 
$$\phi_n(w)=\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbb E\left[e^{iwn^{-1/2}  x_j}\right].$$
Since the random variables $x_j$ are identically distributed, this reduces to $\phi_n(w)=\left(\mathbb E\left[e^{iwn^{-1/2}  x_1}\right]\right)^n$.